# How to set WMS reprojection configuratation in MapServer if creating virtual map (e.g. star map)

Tags: wms, mapserver, epsg, configuration

I want to use OpenLayers with MapServer to create map of stars, but I don't know how to set up the WMS configuration in MapServer, especially the EPSG re-projection aspects.

In fact, I didn't get any re-projection, and I just want to get MapServer to provide a WMS and communicate with OpenLayers.

Can anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 2):

In case you want your mapserver to provide WMS layer, which is reprojected on the fly you will require GDAL to be configured with your MapServer. If you are on windows a simple solution is installing [MS4W](http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/index.phtml?page=downloads.html). Now your mapfile definition could be as simple as follows:

```
    MAP
        NAME USA
        STATUS ON
        SIZE 800 500
        IMAGETYPE PNG
        IMAGECOLOR 240 240 240
        SHAPEPATH "/var/www/html/data"
        UNITS dd
      # The projection object is typically used within the map and the layer
      # objects. You only define it once within the map object and this definition
      # becomes your output projection--MapServer will render your maps in this
      # projection.  You also use the projection object within the layer object to 
      # define your input projection.  Your layers can be in different 
      # projections--MapServer will reproject them into your output projection.
        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:4326"
        END
        WEB
            IMAGEPATH "/var/www/html/tmp/"
            IMAGEURL "/tmp/"
        END

        LAYER
            NAME "US state boundaries"
            TYPE POLYGON
            STATUS ON
            DATA "statesp020"
            PROJECTION
                # projection for the Continental U.S.
                  "proj=laea"
                  "ellps=clrk66"
                  "lat_0=45"
                  "lon_0=-100"
            END
            CLASS
                NAME "US states"
                OUTLINECOLOR 60 60 60
                COLOR 255 255 0
                SYMBOL 0
            END
        END 
    END
```

Here your input projection is Lambert Azimuthal Equal-Area (for US state boundaries layer) and your output is geographic (latlong) projection using the WGS84 datum

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!  In fact, I just put       PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:4326"
        END